# Saving OneToOne mapped object in the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, one-to-one

I'm trying to save a UserOnline object, which has a OneToOne relationship with User, in the database. I want to create a new one if it doesn't exist, and if it does exist, simply change the room.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    UserOnline uo = (UserOnline) UserOnline.find("byUser",
            getConnectedUser()).first();

    if (uo == null) {
        uo = new UserOnline(getConnectedUser(), room);
        room.save();
    } else {
        uo.currentRoom = room;
        uo.save();
    }
```

For some reason, even though the uo is actually null, the object isn't actually saved. Any ideas why that is? It's not giving me an error, it just isn't creating the record. I'm also wondering how I could create a UserOnline object starting from the User object.

Something like

```
User user = User.findById(1);
user.onlineStatus.room = room.
user.save();
```

Can related objects be (created if they don't exist and otherwise edited) saved this way?

## User.java

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
public UserOnline onlineStatus;
```

The save() method is [from the play framework.](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/GenericModel.java)

Comment: Can you provide more code? E.g. the save() function and how the relationship between the object is modeled...

Comment: The save() method is from the play framework, I should have mentioned that. Post updated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this question is related to Play Framework. If so, it would be better to mark it as such, since use of Hibernate in Play Framework has some pecularities, see [Explicit save](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jpa#save).

Regarding the question, Play Framework's `save()` is cascaded on relationships that have `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` on them. If your relationship in question is configured this way, it should work fine.

Comment: My current code seems to be working with the Cascade option. Can I also create my useronline object from the user object this way?